# How to add a new column that have a unique number for continuous integers in an existing column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df`, with a column `x`:

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9))
```

I want to add a new column `y` to `df`. `y` must be the same number if the rows are continuous integers (e.g. 2, 3 - second and third rows). If the number is not continued (e.g. 1, in the first row) it has to have its own unique number.

Desired output:

```
  x y
1 1 1
2 3 2
3 4 2
4 7 3
5 8 3
6 9 3
```

Comment: Something like `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$x) != 1))`

Comment: ^ This means, "take the cumulative sum of a vector that combines one TRUE value (since row 1 is defined as different from the nothing that came before) and then a vector that evaluates if the difference between two successive elements is different from 1" -- in other words, count how many times so far that x has changed by more or less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```r
df = data.frame(x = c(1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9))

y <- 1
j <- 1
for (i in 1:(length(df$x) - 1)) {
  if (df$x[[i + 1]] - df$x[[i]] == 1) {
    y <- c(y , j)
  } else{
    y <- c(y , j + 1)
    j <- j + 1
  }
}

cbind(df , y)
#>   x y
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 3 2
#> 3 4 2
#> 4 7 3
#> 5 8 3
#> 6 9 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>